# Increasing the size of online redo log file?

Tags: database, oracle10g

How to increase the size of online redo log file while the database is online?

Is there anyway to resize once its been created?

Answer (score 0):

You can change redo_buffer in parameter file.

```
edit the initxxx.ora file 
log_buffer=123456 
save the initxxx.ora
```

Alternatively you can use the below query as well.

Give following command at sqlplus (user must be a sysdba)

```
alter system set log_buffer = 123456 scope=spfile;
```

and then restart your database.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot resize redo log files. We need to drop each group and recreate it.

For a detailed answer, please check the [AskTom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:55812348055) link. Hope this helps.